# Javascript - Create new Date using a UK format and moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a date in UK format "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" and I want to create a new date with javascript. I'm trying the following using moment.js but it doesn't recognise the timepart and simply adds on the current time.

```
 var myDate = "11/10/2016 09:00"

 // The toDate() is equivalent to the javascript new Date() function
 var newDate = moment(myDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").val()).toDate();

 // output:
 // 20161011T091406Z 
 // Tue Oct 11 2016 09:14:06 GMT+0100
```

As you can see its changed the time part to the time the script is run.

Comment: Your date format doesn't appear to match the input at all - is that intentional?

Comment: As suggested, you have to correct your format to the one matching your input string. You will have: `var newDate = moment(myDate, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toDate();`

Comment: @jonrsharpe and VincenzoC both of you are incorrect. I'm using moment.js to parse the existing format to a javascript iso format. Reads the moment docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @adam78 I'm happy that you solved your issue using the hint in my previous comment (so both jonrsharpe and me were right) :)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out myself by doing the following:

```
var myDate = "11/10/2016 09:00"

myDate  = moment(myDate, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toISOString();

var newDate = moment(myDate).toDate();
```

Comment: You're parsing a string to a moment object that is then output as a string that you then parse again to a moment object and call *toDate*, which is inefficient. Try `moment(myDate, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toDate()` as  VincenzoC suggested. Or write a 2 line function to do the same thing.